# How to access the `<svg>` Element in `UseEffect()` in React?

Tags: reactjs, dom, getelementsbytagname

I have a React website in which I display a React-Icon:

`import { BsHouse } from 'react-icons/bs';`

It gets rendered as a SVG which I can access in the Firefox Developer Tools:
[image]

But when I try to access it in `UseEffect()` on my React page, it is null:

`const path = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]; // null`

Although I can access other tags such as `body`, `div`, `a` etc.

It appears that the `<svg>` and `<path>` elements haven't been rendered at this point.

**Where and when can I access `<path>` in my React page after they are rendered in DOM?**